# Inequality of limits

Tags: real-analysis, solution-verification

I want to prove that given $f$ and $g$ such that for all $x$, $f(x) \leqslant g(x)$, then the limit of $f$ at $a$ is less or equal than the limit of $g$ at $a$, provided they both exist. Let us call them respectively $l_1$ and $l_2$

So far, I have done this. We have a $\delta$ for any $\varepsilon$ such that: if $|x-a| < \delta$, then both $|f(x)-l_1| < \varepsilon$ and $|g(x) -l_2| < \varepsilon$ hold. Now, by the reverse triangle inequality I have said that this means that $|f(x)| - |l_1| < \varepsilon$ and $|g(x)| - |l_2| < \varepsilon$. Now, I don’t know what to do to compare l1 and l2 effectively. Please, don’t spoil the answer, just give me some useful and justified hints.

Comment: I believe you're thinking a bit too complicated. For brevity, let $h(x) = g(x) - f(x)$. By assumption we have $h(x) \geq 0$, and since $\lim_{x\rightarrow a} g(x)$ and $\lim_{x\rightarrow a} f(x)$ exists, we conclude that also $\lim_{x\rightarrow a} h(x)$ exists. Can you take if from here?

Comment: If you are interested in an $ \epsilon$ - $\delta$ proof, try using Proof by contradiction - assume that the limit of $f$ at $a$ is strictly larger than that of $g$ and see where it leads.

Comment: @stange  Thanks, I will let you know once I get back to it tomorrow.

Comment: @shortmanikos Thanks, I will try it and see if I can get to the goal.

Comment: @stange From that point, I said that the limit of the function h at a equals to l2 -  l1 and since h is always greater or equal to zero, this difference must be greater or equal to zero, which means that l2 must be greater or equal to l1.